# Stack overflow Фибоначчи

Tags: c++, stackoverflow

стоит задача вычислить n число Фибоначчи. Вроде все работает, но на числах больше 1000(на глаз :) программа прерывается из-за Stack overflow. Кто может подсказать причину данного проишествия? Мне не хватает вместительности переменной? Или же есть какой-то иной путь решения задачи(точнее записи промежуточных значений)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
long fibo(int n)
{
    if (n<=2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n ;
    cout << fibo(n);    
}
```

Comment: Я бы создал список уже имеющихся значений (начально - 2 значения, две единицы, ну или для чистоты - пустой), и вместо вычисления уже имеющихся брал из этого списка. А рекурсию строил в обратном направлении - увеличение от 1 до достижения значения аргумента.

Comment: Она что, реально у вас работает при числах, больших 50? не верю... Кстати, при больших n числа просто не помещаются в ваш `long`... — см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/604409/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-100%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%a4%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d1%87%d0%b8/604433#604433

Answer (score 0):

Вы вызываете метод fibo рекурсией. Если посмотрите в стек вызовов то увидите что каждый вызов этого метода создаёт ещё несколько рекурсий этого же метода вот здесь

```
return fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2);
```

Неплохая статья для примера возможного решения.
https://habr.com/ru/post/261159/
Я бы использовал цикл внутри метода.

Comment: тоесть рекурсией не стоит это считать? или же есть способ выехать с этой ошибки все еще используя рекурсию?

Comment: @MyLittleMasya Если непременно нужна рекурсия, то сохраняйте посчитанные значения в списке и берите оттуда, а не считайте заново

Comment: просто  это очень хорошая задача, что бы показать рекурсию и одновременно, это хорошая задача, что бы показать, как рекурсия может плохо работать, если применять ее в лоб.

Comment: Точно там же нужно ещё и второе значение в цикл тогда загнать.Да верно предыдущий вариант был совсем неверен

Comment: Вот в этом  ответе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1325691/1325696#1325696 примерно с середины написано про вычисление последовательности Фибоначчи. И про мемоизацию. И есть ссылка на короткую статью про рекурсии.

Answer (score 0):

Код ниже, он будет работать с небольшими числами, если пишет "stack overflow" то это скорее памяти не хватает для записи числа.

```
int fibonacci_number(int pos)
{
    if (pos < 2)
        return pos;
    return fibonacci_number(pos - 1) + fibonacci_number(pos - 2);
}
```

Что б выделить больше памяти, следует писать так:

```
long long fibonacci_number_fast(long long pos, long long a = 0, long long b = 1)
{
    if (pos == 0)
        return a;
    return fibonacci_number_fast(pos - 1, b, a + b);
}
```

Вторая функция будет очень быстро обрабатывать большие числа.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).